# Getting 404 response for rest/login call in JasperReports server 7.1

Tags: jasperserver

I have installed JasperReports Server 7.1.0 and I am trying to hit rest/login call from browser and postman but the response is 404.

In 7.1.0 most of the rest API's are deprecated.

But in the documentation, it is clearly mentioned that rest/login is still supported.

Can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to like the answer I got, but pretty much you need to use:

HTTP:/server:port/j_spring_security_check?j_username=username&j_password=password

That will return you the cookie and a 302 response. Which is crazy! Then you have to check the location header on the response. If you get "/loginsuccess.html" then you're golden. Otherwise, there was an error.

https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-rest-api-reference/v710/authentication#The_Security_Check